upgrade angular application from 13 to 17 configuration issue

i got through the angular upgrade steps guide to upgrade my application, through the steps I was fixing the code changes and I had another issue which is the packages conflicts.
once I complete and solve all code and packages issues, i got a strange error related to all the application component, they are 2 issues. And I think it is something related to the configurations setup

this is the packages json file which contains all packages in the application and its versions
{
  "name": "UpgradeApplication",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js --mode development --stats-error-details",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode production --stats-error-details",    
    "_start": "ng serve",
    "_build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.0.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^17.0.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet-draw": "^17.0.1",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.15",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.11.1",
    "@azure/web-pubsub-client": "^1.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-dynamic-import": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods": "^7.24.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/core": "^5.7.4",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^5.0.8",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^5.0.7",
    "@ctrl/ngx-csv": "^6.0.0",
    "@hapi/boom": "^10.0.1",
    "@hapi/cryptiles": "^6.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.8.3",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^11.0.1",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^4.0.0",
    "@mapbox/togeojson": "^0.16.2",
    "@mirei/leaflet-semicircle-ts": "^1.0.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^17.1.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^17.1.1",
    "@raruto/leaflet-elevation": "^2.5.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.1.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^6.5.0",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.55.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.13",
    "@types/karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.4",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.9",
    "@types/leaflet-draw": "^1.0.11",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^17.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^5.3.3",
    "color": "^4.2.3",
    "core-js": "^3.36.1",
    "echarts": "^5.5.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "ionic-selectable": "^5.0.3",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet-draw": "^1.0.4",
    "leaflet-geosearch": "^3.11.1",
    "leaflet-minimap": "^3.6.1",
    "leaflet-sidebar-v2": "^3.2.3",
    "leaflet.elevation": "^0.0.3",
    "minimist": "^1.2.8",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "mt-latlon": "^0.1.2",
    "ngx-echarts": "^17.1.0",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.12.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "svgo": "^3.2.0",
    "togeojson": "^0.16.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "xmldom": "^0.6.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~17.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.3.3",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^5.7.4",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^17.3.3",
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.5",
    "@types/color": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.7",
    "@types/glob": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.4",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.13",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/leaflet-draw": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "48.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-ngrx": "^2.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.2",
    "typescript": "~5.4.4",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}


the tsconfig json that indicate how the application and code will be look like
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "app/*"
      ]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "e2e"
  ]
}

this is the webpack config js

const { AngularWebpackPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    fallback: {
      url: require.resolve('url/'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: '@ngtools/webpack',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new AngularWebpackPlugin({
      tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};


This is the first errors i have which i am sure that all files have no issues as mentioned

ERROR in ./src/app/pages/home/table/table-headers-modal/table-headers-modal.component.ts 2:0-51
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/app/utils.functions' in 'D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\home\table\table-headers-modal'
resolve 'src/app/utils.functions' in 'D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\home\table\table-headers-modal'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/pages/home/table/table-headers-modal)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
resolve as module
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\home\table\table-headers-modal\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\home\table\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\home\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
looking for modules in D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\node_modules
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\node_modules\src doesn't exist
D:\GIT\Master\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
./src/app/pages/home/table/table.component.ts 16:0-74 439:330-359 ./src/app/pages/home/home.component.ts 14:0-46 145:58-75
./src/app/pages/home/home-routing.module.ts 2:0-49 8:19-32
./src/app/pages/home/home.module.ts 13:0-58 25:12-29
./src/app/pages/main/main-routing.module.ts 12:36-65
./src/app/pages/main/main.module.ts 7:0-58 13:12-29
./src/app/pages/app-container/app-container-routing.module.ts 14:36-65
./src/app/pages/app-container/app-container.module.ts 12:0-75 19:12-37
./src/app/app-routing.module.ts 21:28-80
./src/app/app.module.ts 3:0-56 122:12-28
./src/main.ts 3:0-45 8:54-63

same error for another component

ERROR in ./src/app/pages/home/table/table.component.ts 3:0-71
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'src/app/utils.functions' in 'D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\home\table'
resolve 'src/app/utils.functions' in 'D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\home\table'
Parsed request is a module
using description file: D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\package.json (relative path: ./src/app/pages/home/table)
Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
resolve as module
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\home\table\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\home\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\pages\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\app\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\src\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
looking for modules in D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\node_modules
D:\GIT\Master\Netcell\node_modules\src doesn't exist
D:\GIT\Master\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\GIT\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
@ ./src/app/pages/home/home.component.ts 14:0-46 145:58-75
@ ./src/app/pages/home/home-routing.module.ts 2:0-49 8:19-32
@ ./src/app/pages/home/home.module.ts 13:0-58 25:12-29
@ ./src/app/pages/main/main-routing.module.ts 12:36-65
@ ./src/app/pages/main/main.module.ts 7:0-58 13:12-29
@ ./src/app/pages/app-container/app-container-routing.module.ts 14:36-65
@ ./src/app/pages/app-container/app-container.module.ts 12:0-75 19:12-37
@ ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts 21:28-80
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts 3:0-56 122:12-28
@ ./src/main.ts 3:0-45 8:54-63

 once i make the npm start I will have a bunch like these errors. almost all my component all over the application. I have checked all the files and paths and they are correct and no errors. Also, no error in ts or html files related and mentioned
now the second issue is the scss files are not correctly loaded into the application. I have added them in different way I will explain them after the error's samples. also, the same of the first issue, I have more than these errors but related to different files or component. But I cannot mention them all. 

**the second error list**
ERROR in The loader "D:/GIT/Master/Netcell/src/app/app.component.scss" didn't return a string.
ERROR in The loader "D:/GIT/Master/Netcell/src/app/common-components/chips/chips.component.scss" didn't return a string.
ERROR in The loader "D:/GIT/Master/Netcell/src/app/common-components/drop-dowm-select/drop-down-select.component.scss" didn't return a string.
ERROR in The loader "D:/GIT/Master/Netcell/src/app/common-components/faults-filters-modal/faults-filters-modal.component.scss" didn't return a string.


I have tried angular upgrade guide and steps, also stack overflow to solve some issue through the process.
Please let me know if you need any other clarification or another information to solve this issue.
I think it is something related to the configuration but I could not figure it out.

